# Java Lang Out Of Memory Error Android

Tags: android, xamarin

So im getting this error once again. I got imagebuttons and imagebutton styles. So 1 for idle and 1 for pressed situation.(In total its like 300 kb) .
Is 300 kb buttons too much for android?

Comment: `kb` ? Are you saying you have 300 `Button` classes instanced and visible within one Activity?

Comment: 300 kilobayts of imagebutton icons per button. I have like 10-15 imagebuttons.

Comment: The "on-disk size" of the image is not the important factor, it is the resolution. In an Android `RGBA` image, a 500x500 image is 1MB of memory but in `jpg/png` format it might only be 30KB on disk. Review the Android bitmap guide and profile your app for memory & GPU usage: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html Low density and medium density Android devices only alloc 16/24MB of ram to your app so memory management of bitmaps on these type of devices is critical....

Comment: I got it. Thank you